# View iPhone/XCode XIB's in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, xcode, xib

I am looking for a good way to view layouts for iPhone written in XCode in Eclipse. I don't need to compile any Objective C code, but it would really help me if I could see XIB's in my Eclipse IDE where I do all of my Android development.  Is there an XIB or NIB editor/viewer for Eclipse?  I am porting apps from iPhone to Android, and it would save me a lot of time to simply view the XIB in an "Editor" mode.

Also, XCode is off limits because I am running Windows 7 with iOS virtualization *off limits* due to Apple TOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .xib is simply an xml file.  Xcode interprets the .xib into a .nib internally.  If you want to see a visual representation, I'm pretty sure you'll have to open it in Xcode 4 or Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but I am on Windows 7, now clarified in the edit :)